# Iteration in JSTL over map fails

Tags: jstl

Why code below fails with *Property 'value' not found on type java.lang.String* ?

```
   <c:set var="map" scope="request">
        <%= new HashMap<String, String>() {{ 
            put("key1", "value1");
            put("key2", "value2");
            put("key3", "value3");
            put("key4", "value4");
            put("key5", "value5");
            put("key6", "value6");
        }} %>
    </c:set>

    <c:forEach var="item" items="${map}">
        ${item.value} <br/>
    </c:forEach>
```

However it succeeds if servlets sets the map attribute and then forwards to JSP!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if value is in `<c:set>` body then **string** value is assigned to variable.
Code bellow works like a charm!

```
<c:set var="map" scope="request" value="<%= new HashMap<String, String>() {{ put(\"key1\", \"value1\"); put(\"key2\", \"value2\"); put(\"key3\", \"value3\"); put(\"key4\", \"value4\"); put(\"key5\", \"value5\"); put(\"key6\", \"value6\"); }} %>" />

<c:forEach var="item" items="${map}">
    ${item.key} <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
   <%=
    HashMap hashMap=     new HashMap<String, String>() {{ 
            put("key1", "value1");
            put("key2", "value2");
            put("key3", "value3");
            put("key4", "value4");
            put("key5", "value5");
            put("key6", "value6");
        }} 
    request.setAttribute("map", hashMap);
     %>


    <c:forEach var="item" items="${map}">
        ${item.value} <br/>
    </c:forEach>
```

You are mixing scriptlet with jstl type of coding, it is considered bad code practice see following [link1](http://www.coderanch.com/t/292091/JSP/java/Mixing-JSTL-Scriplets), [link2](http://www.craigsprogramming.com/2011/03/how-to-clean-your-jsp-code-with-jstl.html).

Also, see following for understanding [jsp variable scope](http://strutscr.uw.hu/0059.html).

Comment: There is nothing wrong (from tech. perspective) to mix JSTL with scriptlets and expressions.

Comment: @robert I updated my answer, it is considered bad practice most of the time.

Comment: I agree that it is bad design but my question was not about design :) The code was not failing because of bad design.